# Como capturar o erro: SERVER RESPONDS REQUEST-URI TOO LONG, STATUS = 414

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um aplicativo de chat, que abre um arquivo (via file input) e então converte em DATA URI. (Estou usando PubNub) quando eu envio a string, recebo um erro de 'URI too long'. Como eu posso compactar a URI, ou ao mínimo capturar esse erro? (try..catch parece não funcionar)

```js
//LOCAL GLOBAL VAR TECHNIQUE
  var rethtml = "";
  
  function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById('inputImg').files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;

        //shortening the name, and also making the local variable public (for other purposes)
        rethtml = newImage.outerHTML;
        
        //CHANGING LOCAL IMG
        document.getElementById("imgTestLocal").innerHTML=rethtml;
        
        //SENDING TO SERVER CHAT
      pubnub.publish({channel : channel,message : rethtml});
  
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
   
    }
  }
```

```css
.fileContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}

img {
  
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    font-size: 999px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
}

#bwui_file{ 

 background-color:#222;
 color:#fff;
 display:block;
 padding:0;
 margin:10px;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 transition:500ms;
 font-size:15pt;
 text-align:center;
 border:none;
 outline:none;
 border-radius:50%;
}

.fileContainer:hover > #bwui_file { 

 margin:5px;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 background-color:#fff;
 color:#222;
 font-size:20pt;
 transition:500ms;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
Ele funciona perfeitamento aqui (carregando a imagem localmente) mas quando eu tento enviar uma imagem muito pesada, somente a local carrega..

<div class="fileContainer">

<input type="button" value="➕" id="bwui_file"/>

<input id="inputImg" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />

</div>
LOCAL:
<div id="imgTestLocal" width="10px" height="10px"></div>
PUBNUB (preciso deste para o chat):
<div id="imgTest" width="10px" height="10px"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.0.11.min.js"></script>

<script>

var pubnunb;
  pubnub = new PubNub({ publishKey : 'demo', subscribeKey : 'demo' });
  
  function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
  var box = $('content'), channel = 'snippet';
  
    //CHAT RECEIVE
  pubnub.addListener({
    message: function(obj) {
     document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML=obj.message;
      alert(obj.message);
        
    }});
      pubnub.subscribe({channels:[channel]});
      
      

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Esse `return rethtml;` não faz sentido algum, pois a função esta dentro onchange.

Comment: Esse `return rethtml;` **ainda** não faz sentido algum, pois a função esta dentro onchange.

Comment: verdade, porquê todo o valor que eu preciso, está no "rethtml = newImage.outerHTML" {e... ja foi editado}